# Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'ErrorSummary' when performing platform check Flutter web

Tags: flutter-web

I have bottom navigation bar that switches between two screens `BookingsScreen` and `OpeningTimesScreen`. My problem is that `OpeningTimesScreen` UI doesn't load properly the first time. It does load if tap on its icon again or if I select `BookingsScreen` first and then select it.
As the full UI is quite crowded with 28 textfields and 14 switches, I just reduced it to only one textfield and did some tests. 
It seems that the problem is with textfield declared inside a ternary, thing that I do as the app runs on web and on tablets..

If I declare the textfield as Column's direct child UI builds correctly.

```
TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                controller: monMorOp,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                },
              ),
```

If I declare it in an expanded widget UI still builds correctly.

```
Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                  controller: monMorOp,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

If I declare it without checkin platform UI still builds correctly.

```
Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  //title row
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Monday'),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                        controller: monMorOp,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

When I do perform the platform checking then I get the error and a grey screen at first load only. Once you tap on the BottomNavigationBar icon again it loads fine.

```
Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  //title row
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Monday'),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Platform.isIOS
                          ? CupertinoTextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                              controller: monMorOp,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                              },
                            )
                          : TextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                              controller: monMorOp,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                              },
                            ),
                    ),
```

From Chrome console I see the `Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'ErrorSummary'` with `js_primitives.dart:47` link.

Clicking it opens a tab with this:

`Could not load content for org-dartlang-sdk:///lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/js_primitives.dart (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)`

..I also have another error when app starts and I don't know if they're related..

`favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)`

What can I check to see what's causing it?
As always thank you very much for your time and help.

I also put the entire class :

```
class OpeningTimesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final FixitUser user;
  final LatLng coordinates;
  final String cityDb;
  final String regionDb;
  final String countryDb;
  const OpeningTimesScreen(
      {Key key,
      @required this.user,
      @required this.coordinates,
      @required this.cityDb,
      @required this.regionDb,
      @required this.countryDb})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OpeningTimesScreenState createState() => _OpeningTimesScreenState();
}

// TODO expanded causes error : Another exception was thrown: Instance of 'ErrorSummary'
class _OpeningTimesScreenState extends State<OpeningTimesScreen> {
  TextEditingController monMorOp = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<OpeningTimesBloc>(
      lazy: false,
      create: (BuildContext context) =>
          OpeningTimesBloc()..add(LoadOpeningTimes(widget.user)),
      child: BlocConsumer<OpeningTimesBloc, OpeningTimesState>(
        listener: (BuildContext context, OpeningTimesState state) {},
        builder: (context, state) => Container(
          color: Colors.black54,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 100, vertical: 50),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              //                                                              TODO titles
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        '',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Opening'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Closing'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Active'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Opening'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Closing'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Active'),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              // TODO UI builds without a problem
//              TextField(
//                keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
//                controller: monMorOp,
//                onChanged: (value) {
//                  monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
//                },
//              ),

              // TODO UI builds without a problem
//              Expanded(
//                flex: 1,
//                child: TextField(
//                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
//                  controller: monMorOp,
//                  onChanged: (value) {
//                    monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
//                  },
//                ),
//              ),
              // TODO UI builds without a problem
              //                                                              TODO monday
//              Expanded(
//                flex: 1,
//                child: Row(
//                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
//                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
//                  //title row
//                  children: <Widget>[
//                    Expanded(
//                      flex: 2,
//                      child: Text(
//                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Monday'),
//                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
//                      ),
//                    ),
//                    SizedBox(
//                      width: 20,
//                    ),
//                    Expanded(
//                      flex: 2,
//                      child: TextField(
//                        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
//                        controller: monMorOp,
//                        onChanged: (value) {
//                          monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
//                        },
//                      ),
//                    ),
//                  ],
//                ),
//              ),

              // TODO UI build problem
              //                                                              TODO monday
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  //title row
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Text(
                        AppLocalizations.instance.text('Monday'),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Platform.isIOS
                          ? CupertinoTextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                              controller: monMorOp,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                              },
                            )
                          : TextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                              controller: monMorOp,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                              },
                            ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

As the first thing it get checked is a dart.io library it throws an exception..

Adding a first check kISWeb solved it.
I actually thought that failing the Platform.isIOS check automatically unfolded in the other option for web as well, but it needs its own check ..

```
Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: kIsWeb
                      ? TextField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                          controller: monMorOp,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                          },
                        )
                      : Platform.isIOS
                          ? CupertinoTextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                              controller: monMorOp,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                              },
                            )
                          : TextField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                              controller: monMorOp,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                monMorOp.text = validateTimeFormat(value);
                              },
                            ),
                ),
```

Hope it helps others.
Cheers